# Publishing an app in the Apple Enterprise Store, how it works?

Tags: ios, app-store, ipa

I'm working in a corporate hybrid application. The idea is to distribute it only inside of the company.

I was thinking in use (for iOS), the Enterprise Program, but the information in the website is not enough.

The apple site says you can distribute it in-house, what's the meaning of that?, comparing with the normal store, what are the differences? Can I send the .ipa, download it in the apple store or a private store?
How they verify if a person is part of a company or not?

Comment: It is up to you to determine if someone should get the app; You have to publish it in your own "store", which could be a web server on your company Intranet that provides the .ipa or you can distribute the .ipa directly to users who can install it using iTunes or you can use an MDM solution; this last is the recommended approach.  There isn't an Apple provided "enterprise store".  The other major difference is that Enterprise apps are not reviewed by Apple.

Comment: Thank you Paul!, I think it's more clear now!, you can publish the answer if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an "Enterprise Store" in the sense of a store the Apple runs.  It is up to the enterprise to distribute apps to their users from their own "store"; This could be an internal web site that distributes the .ipa file or you can install the .ipa directly on the devices through the configurator or iTunes.

Enterprise app distribution works well with Mobile Device Management (MDM) as you can push apps to a managed device from the central console, and the user isn't prompted to trust the enterprise security certificate.

It is up to the enterprise to determine if someone should get the app, through a method such as requiring a login to the web site, or, as suggested, their device being part of the enterprise MDM.

Aside from the distribution method, the other major difference is that Enterprise apps are not reviewed by Apple.